# C++: Overloading Matrix Operators

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, operator-overloading

I'm taking an OOP course at college, we are supposed to overload the +, -, *, +=, -= and some other operators to handle Matrices operations using only structs and **operator overloading**. I came up with that code, the user enters a ***1D array***, and then that array is turned into a ***2D array*** or a ***matrix***.

The function `createMatrix` will take a 1D-array and then define the number of **Rows** and **Columns** then put the values in that array into the `matrix` struct or in an element in the struct to be specific. then I defined +, - and <<.

It is not complete yet, but the program doesn't output anything and I can't find where the bug is at, is it in the '+' operator or the '<<' operator -which handles the output of the matrices.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct matrix{
    int* data;          //since it is a 1d array which will later be stored in the matrix
    int row, col;
};

void createMatrix(int row, int col, int num[], matrix& mat);    //by reference so that I fetch it by address from memory


matrix operator+ (matrix mat1, matrix mat2){          //Addition
    matrix mat;
    for(int i = 0; i < max(mat1.row*mat1.col, mat2.row*mat2.col); i++){
        mat.data[i] = mat1.data[i] + mat2.data[i];

    }
    return mat;
}

matrix operator- (matrix mat1, matrix mat2){          //Subtraction
    matrix mat;
    for(int i = 0;i < max(mat1.row*mat1.col, mat2.row*mat2.col); i++){
        mat.row = mat1.row - mat2.row;

    }
    return mat;
}

 ostream operator<< (ostream& out, matrix mat){
     for(int i = 0; i < ((mat.row)*(mat.col)); i++){
         if(i % mat.row == 0 ){
             cout<<endl;
         }
         else{out<<mat.data[i]<<" ";}
     }
 }
 int main()
 {
     int row1, col1;
     int row2, col2;

     cout<<"Enter Rows of first matrix: "; cin>>row1;
     cout<<"Enter Cols of first matrix: "; cin>>col1;

     cout<<"Enter Rows of second matrix: "; cin>>row2;
     cout<<"Enter Cols of second matrix: "; cin>>col2;

     int arr1[row1*col1], arr2[row2*col2];
     cout<<"Enter the values you which to add in the first matrix: ";
     for(int i = 0; i < row1*col1; i++){
         cin>>arr1[i];
     }
     cout<<"Enter the values you which to add in the second matrix: ";
     for(int i = 0; i < row2*col2; i++){
         cin>>arr2[i];
     }

     matrix mat1, mat2, mat3;
     createMatrix(row1, col1, arr1, mat1);
     createMatrix(row2, col2, arr2,  mat2);
     mat3 = mat1 + mat2;
    cout<<mat3;

    return 0;
}

void createMatrix(int row, int col, int num[], matrix& mat){
     mat.row = row;
     mat.col = col;
     mat.data = new int [col * row];             //We are trying to make a matrix from a 1d array, so we will stretch the matrix -which is a 2d array
     for(int i = 0; i < col * row; i++){             //in 1-D of size row *col
         mat.data[i] = num[i];                    //Depending on the parameter the data array will be filled dynamically
     }
 }
```

Comment: May or may not be related (don't know what the bug you're looking for is): The compiler may be trying to warn you that `operator<<` is missing a `return` statement.

Comment: `int arr1[row1*col1], arr2[row2*col2];` defines Variable Length Arrays (VLA).  VLAs are not Standard C++. Your compiler may or may not support this behaviour, and if it does, it is a blisteringly easy way to cause a stack overflow. Probably best if you use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: `createMatrix` looks like the sort of thing that should be returning a `matrix`, not taking one as a parameter. To get that to work (and because you can't write worthwhile C++ code without doing this), familiarize yourself with the [Rules of Three, Five, and Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Answer (score 2):

Your operator+ will cause a segfault because you have not allocated mat.data using `new`. You need to do

```
matrix mat;
mat.data = new int [max(mat1.row*mat1.col, mat2.row*mat2.col)];
```

Anyway, your matrix addition logic won't work and will cause another segfault. [I suggest looking at this page](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/examples/add-matrix) for guidance on how to tackle this. It talks about using two-dimensional matrices which should make the logic easier to follow rather than working with 1D array/vector.

So if you had two 2D arrays, `a` and `b`, you could add them like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < min(a_row, b_row); ++i)
    for(j = 0; j < min(b_col, a_col); ++j)
        sum[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
```

Comment: Sidenote: rather than setting all of the parameters of `matrix` after the fact (or forgetting to do so), you should consider giving it a constructor to make this problem impossible.

Comment: I did not know it was better to work with a 1D array so thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you are overloading the `operator<<` who will return a `std::ostream`, you always have to return a reference to it.
Example:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, matrix mat) {
    out << mat.col << mat.data << mat.row;
    return out;
}
```

Also, you can't just make an array whose size it not known at compile time yet. `cin` is an I/O operation. So the size is not known at compile time, but at runtime.